# Android app, dynamic activity window with buttons

Tags: java, android

I am stuck with an idea.

I am trying to implement a feature in a android application.
I have an edittext and a button, if I enter 3 in edittext
and press the button I want to go to another activity which will be having 3 buttons.

If i enter 10 I wanna go to another activity where to display 10 buttons.
I know how to make such switch, I don't know how to do it dynamically ,

I want to make for values between 0 and 10 and I don't want to have 10 fragments .

Plaese give me solution to achieve it ..

Thanks..

Untill now:

mainactivity.java:

```
 package com.example.instances_temperature;

import com.example.instances_temperature.Tabel;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    EditText instances;
    Button ok;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        instances = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.instances);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (instances.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                 {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(instances.getText().toString());;
                if(value > 10)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    if(value<0)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        if(value >= 0 && value <=10)
                        {
                            schimba(v);
                        }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }

            }
        });


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public void schimba(View view){
        int value = Integer.parseInt(instances.getText().toString());;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tabel.class);
        intent.putExtra("max", value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.instances_temperature.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:text="Instances No.:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/instances"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/instances"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:onClick="schimba" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

tabel.java:

```
    package com.example.instances_temperature;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class Tabel extends ActionBarActivity {

    int i;

    int value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabel);
        Intent intentObject = getIntent();
        value = intentObject.getIntExtra("max", 0);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        for(i=1;i<=value;i++)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutinflate = null; 
            layoutinflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            final View rowview = layoutinflate.inflate( R.layout.ShowMe, null);

            TextView showvalue;
            showvalue = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.showid);
            showvalue.setText(""+value);

            layout.addView(rowview);
        }



        //showvalue.setText(String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("max")));


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tabel, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabel,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

activity_tabel.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.instances_temperature.Tabel"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout code of inflation_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inflationn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat error:

```
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.instances_temperature/com.example.instances_temperature.Tabel}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.example.instances_temperature.Tabel.onCreate(Tabel.java:42)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-24 06:21:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value from the editText by...

```
String value= EditText.getText().toString();
```

Pass the value to  another activity (Activity2) through Intent

Now in Activity2 you write this code in the `onCreate()`

```
for(int i=1 ; i<= value ; i++){
    Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());           
    LinearLayout.addView(b);
}
```

Comment: Okey, thanks is very usefull,I was thinking now, I can create a layout and spam it in a for ? There is something more complex, I have like 2 buttons and 2 textviews in a layout and I want that layout to be displayed for x times.The ideea is that I want them to be independent, I want what I modify in a layout to remain in that layout. Can this be done ?

Comment: Yse...You can render a layout x times containing 2 buttons and 2 textviews. Then later you can modify each layout dynamically......

Comment: I do it in the same way as you showed me up ? How I can create the layout and his properties ?

Comment: if you have a complex view then you create it once in xml then inflate and add it in linearlayout in the for loop...

Comment: Can you give me an example step by step how to ? Or a tutorial where to read, I will appreciate, thanks.I made to pass the value to another activity and now I want here to spam the layout x times, every layout containing the same elements and every layout to be independent.

Comment: LayoutInflater layoutinflate = null;

    layoutinflate = (LayoutInflater) 
      getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     final View rowview = layoutinflate.inflate(
      R.layout.your_layout, null);

Comment: design your layout as you may and put this code inside the for loop and add the view to the Layout...

Comment: I designed my layout easy only a textview, I have added the code you showed me in the for loop, how do I add the view to the layout ? Thanks.

Comment: LinearLayout.addView(Your_view);

Comment: I have edited the main post to be easy to read, take a look, I don't know exactly how to do this, eclipse doesn't give me any suggestions how it should be.

Comment: Your main layout should contain a LinearLayout in which you would inflate a layout containing some views.... Are you trying to add a layout x times in activity_table ??

Comment: Yes, I have main activity and I have activity table, I add the values x times in activity_table, in main_activity I only get how many times to add a layout x times in activity_table.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your edited question.....

main xml file activity_table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

layout file to be inflated layout_inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Text" />

 </LinearLayout>

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabel);
Intent intentObject = getIntent();
value = intentObject.getIntExtra("max", 0);
LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout)

for(i=0;i<=value;i++)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutinflate = null; 
    layoutinflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View rowview = layoutinflate.inflate( R.layout.layout_inflate, null);

 TextView showvalue;
showvalue = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.ShowValue);
showvalue.setText(""+value);


layout.addView(rowview);
}
```

Comment: It worked! I have a question, how I can make him to show the same number, I mean: on the main activity I enter 2, in activity_tabel I get 2 textviews: first is 2 and the second is TextView.

Comment: if I do it like you sayd it would display me one good result + x textViews. I entered 4 and it show me 4 + 4x textviews.

Comment: I have shared, I thought it is because I use setText before addview, I switched and putted addview before settext but still if I enter 3 it show me 4 times and it show me correctly only first time.

Comment: it will happen because your main layout activity_table contains a textview and the you r also inflating the same layout 4 times that gives you 5 textviews.... you should inflate a seperate layout containing a textview not your main layout...

Comment: I have created a new layout named: inflation_layout with the id: R.id.inflationn. I have changed the code in:   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.inflationn); and       final View rowview = layoutinflate.inflate( R.layout.inflation_layout, null); getting error on this line:       showvalue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ShowMe); I have changed the id in the new layout of the textview in ShowMe  but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You r not getting me... dont change the linearlayout code.... put a textview in inflation_layout and give its id as ShowMe... remove the textview in activity_table.. and revert back the linearLayout code .... I hope it should work then....

Comment: you should also detect the textview like this showvalue = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.ShowValue); and not like you have written on your code... you have missed out rowview.

Comment: Yes it's working but I get NullPointer Exception now on:       layout.addView(rowview); any ideea ? thanks

Comment: I have shared the linearlayout code, the layout should also have a .java file or it should have only the XML ? I have only the xml.

Comment: Are you using this code... LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container); to detect layout..... and this code...showvalue = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.ShowValue); to detect your rowview in table.java page..... Please confirm....

Comment: I have changed the ID of the layout to: inflationn, so I use   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.inflationn); yes I am using       showvalue = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.ShowMe);

Comment: I have added a logcat error, I get nullPointerException at line 42, this line is :      layout.addView(rowview); something is wrong on the layouts I think.

Comment: See you are not following me.... you want to add the layout inflation_layout x times to your main layout(activity_table)  which contains a Linearlayout (container).... isnt it... Thats why we are not adding the inflation_layout in its own LinearLayout (inflationn)

Comment: Yes, that is correct, we try to add the inflation_layout x times to my layout ( activity_table ), yes he contains a Linearlayout with the ID container. I have updated the tabel.java code with my last code.

Comment: So dont do this.... LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.inflationn); Put ... LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container); and....showvalue = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.ShowMe);

Comment: Yes It's Working now, thanks a lot. Now I can make it however I can right ? with how many buttons and textviews that are independend each set.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the EditText value on tha Button click. And pass the Value with the intent.

In that Activity you can build your logic Using Swicth cases. Then you can add the number of Buttons dynamically (eg:- `for(i=0;i<yourValue;i++)`  yourValue is got From intent.)